# How can I add new values to the beginning of an existing array?

Tags: php

I have an existing array, example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABCD EFGH
    [1] => 123456
    [2] => 7890
)
```

Now I have an existing field with three values.
I would need to split the array with the first value, ie Key [0], and update the existing array with new array values by inserting it at the beginning of the array.
Desired output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABCD
    [1] => EFGH
    [2] => 123456
    [3] => 7890
)
```

i wanted to do an explode () of an existing array [0] `explode(" ", $array[0]);`

and the newly created two array using the function `array_push();`
But the`array_push();` function allows  to update the original array by inserting a new value only at the end of the array.
Is there an easy way to do this? Or do I have to build a new array and extend it with new values by overwriting the entire array?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you open https://www.php.net/array_push and scroll down to the "see also" section you'll see your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks! Array_unshift () function. @zerkms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_unshift` instead of `array_push`

Comment: Thank you. Thank you very much, I have already solved the problem. @Jaya Rathinam

Answer (score 0):

**Data Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABCD EFGH
    [1] => 123456
    [2] => 7890
)

    $newArr = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $res) {
        $exRes = explode(" ", $res);
        foreach ($exRes as $ind => $ex) {
            array_push($newArr, $ex);
        }
    }
```

**Result like this**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABCD
    [1] => EFGH
    [2] => 123456
    [3] => 7890
)
```